Accordian style mobile menu
I'm trying to make a navigation menu using an accordian style dropdown. I've been following some guides online, but I just can't seem to get the JavaScript right. I've managed to get the button to change color when clicked, but I can't get the menu to expand.
Here's the code I have currently.


var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("mobileMenu");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var mmNavLinks = document.querySelector('.mmNavLinks');
    if (mmNavLinks.style.maxHeight) {
      mmNavLinks.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      mmNavLinks.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
.mobileMenu {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* Add border radius to buttons */
  padding: 0px 5px 3px;
  background-color: #bd2a2e;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

@media (min-width: 1191px) {
  .mmNavLinks {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1190px) {
  .mobileMenu {
    display: block;
  }
  .mmNavLinks {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 30%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
  }
  .logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .nav-links {
    display: none;
  }
  nav {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul li {
    margin: 30px 0px;
  }
  #header {
    display: flex;
  }
  hr {
    background-color: white;
  }
  .underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  .sublist {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .active,
  .mobileMenu:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
}
<nav>
  <div id="header">
    <button class="mobileMenu">&#9776;</button>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="files/logos/long_white_text.png" alt="Frameworks Videography Logo">
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    **Truncated for simplicity
  </ul>
  <ul class="mmNavLinks">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <hr size="5">
    <li><span class="underline">For Clients</span>
      <ul class="sublist">
        <li><a href="forms.html">Forms</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://portal.frameworksvideography.com">Payment Portal</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://support.frameworksvideography.com/myportal">Support Portal</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="underline">For Viewers</span>
      <ul class="sublist">
        <li><a href="https://live.frameworks.video/">Livestreams (TicketLeap)</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://youtube.frameworks.video/">YouTube</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://support.frameworksvideography.com/myportal">Support Portal</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>



The current code is also deployed at https://testbed.frameworksvideography.com. You need to shrink the width of your window to see the button.

Your HTML is invalid, only li are permitted children of a ul so  <hr size="5"> is inappropriate. Use a bottom border instead.

I solved my own question! I changed line 7 to "document.querySelectorAll('.mmNavLinks');" opposed to "document.querySelector('.mmNavLinks');"
